# How to do a transaction in a Private Stellar Blockchain Network?

Tags: blockchain, stellar

So using docker I started a private Stellar Network by typing in the below command:
`docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --standalone`
Then I opened another terminal and ran the below command to interact with the private network:
`docker exec -it stellar /bin/bash`
Then I ran the below command to generate a keypair:
`stellar-core --genseed`

All commands went well. How do I do a transaction now?
My objective is to get 333 coins in one of the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Stellar has [a dedicated stackexchange](http://stellar.stackexchange.com/) where questions on Stellar will get more attention.

After you have executed the steps in your question, stellar will be open to receiving transactions at `localhost:8000/tx?blob=Base64` (See [commands](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html)). You can confirm stellar is running with `curl localhost:8000`.

The base64 blob is the the XDR encoded form of a transaction. In your case you will want that transaction to contain a `CreateAccount` operation.

It is possible to build this XDR for custom networks with some of the SDKs. It's possible in the Scala SDK (I'm the maintainer) and probably very easy to do in the JavaScript SDK too. But to start with, I suggest building XDR by hand by going to the [lab's transaction builder](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder), selecting "custom" network at the top right and building your transaction from there.

You want to populate the network passphrase with `Standalone Network ; February 2017`. This is the value in the container's file `stellar-core.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
So I am running a Windows machine, and to execute the above I am using an Amazon EC2 cloud instance and connecting with it using puTTy.
So, I cannot use local host on my own operating system.
So in the below example:
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
Can use the IP address of the VM instead of the URL https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org.
If the answer to the above question is 'Yes', how should I enter the IP, which format will it be in, should I also specify the port like 8000?

Comment: Yes. The port will be `8000`, as you defined `-p "8000:8000"` when starting the docker container. The ip address will be the address of the ec2 instance (name or number is fine), but you would need to define a security group that allows inbound TCP on port 8000.

Comment: So I downloaded node and connected to the localhost:8000 and it got connected. So one last question, now I am using the javascript sdk, what is the javascript code for doing a transaction. And how do I get funds without friendbot. If you can please write an example code. I have gone through this link https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html, but it is not clear enough and more importantly, it talks about using the stellar test network. I am doing everything on an EC2 instance and do not have a GUI, all I have to work with is a terminal (command prompt).

Comment: Great. All the funds are created when the network begins. They belong to the master account. The keypair for the master account is derived from the network passphrase. `var kp = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromRawEd25519Seed(StellarSdk.hash("Standalone Network ; February 2017"))`. You can use this account to issue transactions as per the examples in order to create further accounts.

Comment: ... and looking at this source it seems easy enough to define your own network: https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/node_modules_stellar-base_src_network.js.html

Comment: Thanks for all your help till now. I created the transaction, but to sign it, I need define my own network. Could you please tell me how to define own network. I am using puTTy, all I have is command line tool.

Comment: I found the network.js file, then using vi editor I edited the file and added a static function called useStandAloneNetwork, but I was not able to execute the function on node, then I modified the useTestNetwork function and passed the passphrase of the private network. Then, I was able to sign the transaction while submitting the transaction, I faced an error, "SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol error while executing ssl test". Please see if you can help me here.